# rails app wont initialize on elastic beanstalk with hive_geoip2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, geoip

I have a rails app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk.  When I add the gem `hive_geoip2` it works in development but when I deploy to eb the rails app fails to initialize with the following error:

```
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require': libmaxminddb.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/hive_geoip2-0.1.2/hive_geoip2.so (LoadError)
```

The file in question does exist on the ec2 instance.  I get the same error if I try to start a rails console.

Any insights or suggestions for ways to debug this error would be most welcome.  Thanks in advance.

***Edit***
Here is the relevant eb config section:

```
  03_install_libmaxminddb:
    cwd: /usr/local/src
    command: git clone --recursive https://github.com/maxmind/libmaxminddb.git; cd libmaxminddb; ./bootstrap; ./configure; make; make install; ldconfig
```

Comment: Have you run ldconfig since installing libmaxminddb?

Comment: yes, eb config section added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you don't have `/usr/local/lib` in your ld.so.conf. As root, try running:

```
echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
ldconfig
```

Alternatively, you could create a new file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. You should confirm that `libmaxminddb.so.0` is available in `/usr/local/lib`.